# Build deb package for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04: dependencies issues

Tags: package-management, dependencies, deb

I have a C++ binary application and I package it into a "deb" package on my Ubuntu 20.04. This "deb" package has several dependencies that I have defined:

```
$ dpkg -I my-package-1.0.0.deb 
new Debian package, version 2.0.
...
Package: my-package
Version: 1.0.0
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libfreetype6,libgcc-s1,libgl1,libglew2.1,libglvnd0,libglx0,...
...
```

This package works well except when I try to install it on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i my-package-1.0.0.deb
Selecting previously unselected package my-package.
(Reading database ... 198305 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack my-package-1.0.0.deb ...
Unpacking my-package (1.0.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of my-package:
 my-package depends on libgcc-s1; however:
  Package libgcc-s1 is not installed.
 my-package depends on libglew2.1; however:
  Package libglew2.1 is not installed.
```

These packages in error (`libgcc-s1`, `libglew2.1`) don't exist in Ubuntu 18.04 or exist but with a different version. Therefore, I have a general question:

Is it possible to create "deb" package compatible with several version of Ubuntu? How?

Or the only solution is to build a package for each version of Ubuntu (and for each others Linux distributions)?

What is the most used strategy to build "deb" packages when there are dependencies?

Comment: `dpkg` requires all dependencies to be install at the same time, or already installed. Front end tools like `apt` or `apt-get` can realize this and thus look for packages that will meet requirements, but `dpkg` doesn't.  Your example (*pastes*) highlights a different issue to what you're talking about & thus I'm confused.

Comment: You have no other choice than to adapt your .deb to the distribution version you want it to be installed on. You need to package with only dependencies available on the distribution's version, or provide everything yourself in a way it does not conflict with the system. That is why these "alternative" package formats as flatpak and snap come in: these avoid this limitation of the APT system.

Comment: @karel: in this case, yes, but in general: not necessarily. Indeed some packages install without problem on a future version because the dependencies have not changed a lot. But is is not so by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to create "deb" package compatible with several version of Ubuntu ? How ? Or the only solution is to build a package for each version of Ubuntu (and for each others Linux distributions) ? What is the most used strategy to build "deb" package when there are dependencies ?

Your only solution is to  build a package for each version of Ubuntu (and for each others Linux distribution - even if then you may not be making a `.deb`, but an `.rpm` or any other format these distributions use).

This is indeed a major disadvantage of the traditional APT package system (and competing systems on Redhat and Arch). Your software must be compiled to use the versions of the dependencies that happen to be present on the target system.

This is one of the major motivations that these newer packaging systems such as Snap, Flatpak and Appimage are being developped. These systems allow to package linux software in a way that is much less on the distribution and the distribution version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Vanadium, `.deb` packages need to be created for each version of each distro you want to support. However, I create many packages with C++ executables and libraries and I pretty much never have to list the dependencies (and as a result, I often don't know what they are in the final package).

Here is an example from my [as2js project](https://github.com/m2osw/as2js):

```
Depends: libas2js (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
```

This tells the package builder to add all the dependencies automatically (the `${misc:Depends}` part). The only explicit dependencies I add are dependencies on parts that are created by this very project. Here we see a dependency on the `libas2js` package of the same version.

If you link against dynamic libraries, you also want to include `${shlibs:Depends}` like so:

```
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
```

Now the list gets created from the list of shared libraries found in your libraries and executables. So it is exactly what's necessary on the current system you're running the build on.

If you want to support all the versions currently supported by Ubuntu, I would suggest you use a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esnapcpp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for your code (unless it is for sure 100%). If you can create virtualbox computers, you could also create one instance per OS version you want to support and run the build system on each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:
In Ubuntu 18.04 copy the my-package-1.0.0.deb file to your desktop. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
cd ~/Desktop/
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glew/libglew2.1_2.1.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libglew2.1_2.1.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./my-package-1.0.0.deb
```

The above commands will also work on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. This a fortunate situation. In general don't expect one set of magic commands to work on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu because package dependencies and package dependencies version requirements may be different for the same package in different Ubuntu releases.

In Ubuntu 20.04 the dependency packages are already available in the default Ubuntu repositories so the steps are even easier. Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains my-package-1.0.0.deb, and type:

```
sudo apt install ./my-package-1.0.0.deb
```

Comment: That specific workaround does not explain how to create a .deb file that seamlessly can be installed on both 18.04 and 20.04, which is how I read the question.

Comment: My answer includes two separate groups of  instructions for installing the .deb file in either 18.04 or 20.04. In fact the first set of instructions are so cute that they will work on **both** 18.04 and 20.04 as well as on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree this hack solves this specific issue, but you fail to provide a fundamental answer to the question (I cite) "is it possible to create "deb" package compatible with several version of Ubuntu ?"